# Checking if a channel has a ready-to-read value, using Go

Tags: go, channel

How do I check whether a channel has a value for me to read?

I don't want to block when reading a channel. I want to see whether it has a value. If it does have one, I'll read it. If it doesn't have one (yet), I'll do something else and check back again later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**WARNING**: This is no longer accurate, see the answer below.

<s>From the docs:</s>

> If a receive expression is used in an
>   assignment or initialization of the
>   form
>
> ```
> x, ok = <-ch
> x, ok := <-ch
> var x, ok = <-ch
> ```
>
> the receive operation becomes
>   non-blocking. If the operation can
>   proceed, the boolean variable ok will
>   be set to true and the value stored in
>   x; otherwise ok is set to false and x
>   is set to the zero value for its type

Comment: Warning!  Receive used to work like this but it no longer does.  See Ripounet's answer and above all, check the language spec for the version of Go you are using.

Comment: Props for updating your accepted answer, wish more folks did this

Answer (score 133):

The only non-blocking operation I know of to read from a channel is inside a [select block](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) having a default case :

```
    select {
    case x, ok := <-ch:
        if ok {
            fmt.Printf("Value %d was read.\n", x)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Channel closed!")
        }
    default:
        fmt.Println("No value ready, moving on.")
    }
```

Please [try the non-blocking here](http://play.golang.org/p/FvF5fsZNKt)

**Note about previous answers:** the receive operator itself **is** now a blocking operation, as of Go 1.0.3 . The [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) has been modified. Please [try the blocking here](http://play.golang.org/p/0yurtWW4Q3) (deadlock)

Comment: This can be combined with a ticker when used in a forever loop, for periodic checks. The ticker will prevent tight loops.

Comment: @AJPennster Well, the point of the default blocking behavior is, among other things, to eliminate the need of various kinds of busy-looping. The "non-blocking read" code should IMO be avoided if possible. And if you're spinning in tight loops or even loose ticking loops around the "non-blocking read", then you're most probably using it very wrong. Prefer properly decoupled goroutines, with blocking reads.

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately, the previous answers are incorrect. The [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) clearly says that you CAN use channels this way using len() function, but only if you specified the channel capacity - the buffer length for a channel while making it. If you omitted a channel capacity while making it - the channel operations are always blocking.

Comment: Was looking for a performance comparison of the 2 as I'm doing thousands of checks per second. Using `len()` is about 7x faster than a `select{}` with go 1.9.1. https://gist.github.com/phemmer/428685f5366c4b71b39d1037e6124a73

Comment: Wouldn't your `len()` implementation have a race condition? I.E. two goroutines could see `len(chn) != 0` and then block when they run `v := <-chn` since only one would actually get the value.

Comment: @JohnGibb - If the number of readers was known, every reader could avoid reading until all readers would succeed. ;-) In the case of one reader, then the check != 0 would be just fine.

Answer (score 15):

If you're doing this often then it's probably not a great design and you might be better off spawning another goroutine to do whatever work you're planning to do when there isn't anything to read from the channel. The synchronous/blocking nature of Go's channels make code easier to read and reason about while the scheduler and cheap goroutines means that async calls are unnecessary since waiting goroutines take up very little resources.

Comment: This should be the correct answer and I wish had more up votes. You shouldn't have two different workflows depending on if a channel has something available or not. You are likely trying to do to much with one channel, need to restructure your program, or need an additional channel.

Answer (score 10):

You don't, at least not for synchronous (unbuffered) channels.  There is no way to tell if a value is waiting without asking to take the value from the channel.

For buffered channels, you technically can use the len function to do what you describe, but you really, really shouldn't.  Your technique is invalid.

The reason is that it represents a race condition.  Given channel ch, your goroutine might see that len(ch) > 0 and conclude that there is a value waiting.  It cannot conclude however, that it can read from the channel without blocking--another goroutine might empty the channel between the time you check len and the time your receive operation runs.

For the purpose you described, use select with a default case as Ripounet showed.

Comment: "It cannot conclude however, that it can read from the channel without blocking" -- unless it knows that it is the only one listening/reading.

Answer (score -4):

In most cases relying on such information is a really bad design choice. Not even saying about how it's dirty in it's implementation.

So, **do not  implement the following steps** to detect if channel is ready for read at runtime:

- define **hchan** **waitq** **sudog** structs as defined here - https://golang.org/src/runtime/chan.go
- use "unsafe" package to cast channel to pointer to **hchan** struct
- read **sendq** field of this struct to get listeners
- read **first** **sudog** and read msg field from there.
- cast msg to the appropriate type for the channels using "reflect" and "unsafe"

Comment: Why would doing that be a bad design choice?  Why shouldn't those particular steps be followed?  Is there a better way to implement something that will solve the problem?

Comment: Because from concurrency standpoint this introduces invisible channel that hold information about value existence on original channel.
The steps i've described should not be followed for sarcastic reasons.
A better implementation would be to explicitly create another channel holding info about original one.

Comment: That information should be in your answer, including the "correct" way to do things.  Sarcastic answers that aren't meant to be followed aren't good answers.

Comment: @ArtemCo, the concept of the "invisible channel" is interesting and gave me something to think about. Pity that you didn't make it the basis of your answer and elaborate on it.